# Which process is using my NAS?

Tags: network-attached-storage, cluster, write

I have a nas connected to my cluster. The NAS holds all our home directories. When I did a set of experiments last week, saving a 1 GB file to the nas took around 30 seconds. If i do the same to a local disk it takes 18 seconds. But when I tried doing the same process today, it takes 150 seconds. I am unsure what is the problem . Can someone help me pointout the issue? Is it possible to find out which process is accessing the NAS or how much NAS bandwidth is getting used ? Thanks for your help.

-Sethu

Comment: It would probably as to what type of NAS you are running as well as the clients that are connected to the NAS.

Comment: Please specify your environment. Are you using Windows or Linux clients? What type of NAS is it? What cluster are you talking about? What protocol are you using to access your NAS (CIFS, NFS)?